# Prism Xamarin OnNavigatedTo will not execute a function

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, prism

I have my application designed using Xamarin Prism .
I have a command that should be executed when the user navigate to this given page .
it runs in a different project , but when I rewrote the same code , it will not run .
I compared the codes and almost identical . however , it still will not run in this code .

first I defined the command :

```
public IAsyncCommand InitCommand { get; }
```

in my view model constructor I have this code :

```
InitCommand = new AsyncCommand(InitAsync);
```

and this is my InitAsync method :

```
private async Task InitAsync()
{

    await GetTransactionsByWallet(WalletId).ConfigureAwait(false); ;

}
```

and in my  OnNavigatedTo part of prism , i have this code :

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
{
    WalletId = parameters.GetValue<IWallets>("wallet").Id;
    InitCommand.ExecuteAsync();
}
```

note :
`InitCommand.ExecuteAsync();`  will not execute even if i put a stop at it to debug it , the debugger also wont stop to it .

im using AsyncAwaitBestPractices.MVVM for the creation of the command .

Comment: `debugger also wont stop to it` means OnNavigatedTo not being called when you navigate pages.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT this line WalletId = parameters.GetValue<IWallets>("wallet").Id; gets executed normally .. but this will not execute the line after

Comment: Would it execute if you remove  `WalletId = parameters.GetValue<IWallets>("wallet").Id;`? If so,  `WalletId = parameters.GetValue<IWallets>("wallet").Id;` blocked the method.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT yes , it blocks it i commented it out ! how to fix it ?

Comment: I don't use prism and I wonder if you have use it correct. [Here](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/passing-parameters.html#reading-parameters) is the document I searched and it is different of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you have decided to run the command rather than the method directly? i.e. instead of `InitCommand.ExecuteAsync();` why not just `await InitAsync()`.

Note: you can make OnNavigatedTo an async method. And since it is an eventhandler (the events being fired during navigation), async void is allowed - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming

Here - https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/91897/prism-calling-async-method-in-onnavigatedto-or-any-of-the-methods-from-inavigationaware
As mentioned by Brian Lagunas (manager of the Prism Library)

But if that option doesnt sound good - another option is to run the method during the "Loaded" event of the view. These are not workarounds, these are the proper mvvm ways to do this. For running the method on loaded, you have two ways of doing it -

(1) Use Xaml Behavior Library's CallMethodAction or
(2) Use Prism's inbuilt InvokeCommandAction with the XAML Interactivity.